# TV episode or movie in which investigators visit a town where people go insane if they hear "The Secret"

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I once saw a show where investigators go to a town where people are going crazy.  Eventually, they find out that anyone who hears "The Secret" goes insane.  In the final scene the investigators are about to flee to town and stop to pickup some kids.  One of the investigators picks up a kid who whispers something into the investigator's ear.  The investigator's eyes go wide and he starts screaming.

I cannot remember where I saw this and it's driving me nuts!  Please help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: While not a TV show or a movie, this reminds me of the video for Radiohead's "Just".

Comment: While it's not what you're looking for, I'm reminded of the Monty Python "Killer Joke" sketch.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

["Need to Know"](http://www.steveandmarta.com/need%20to%20know/ntz_need_to_know_synopsis.html) - an episode of the 1980s version of The Twilight Zone:

> The conceit of the story is that a whispered phrase is sending these people instantly bonkers, so it's a race against time for the main protagonist to get back to his fiance before someone whispers the phrase to her.
> William Petersen and Frances McDormand play an engaged couple, and they are both excellent, as always.  This segment is more like "The Jeopardy Room," from the original Twilight Zone, where there is no fantasy element and it's up to the hero to save the day.  But this type of story has inherent issues.  How do you stop something like this from spreading?  The infected seem to have no more zealous ambition in life than to infect others.  Mass murder, so that the "whispers" are contained to the small town?  How do you know who to kill?  The episode never really gets round to any of that.  Our quest stops when the hero makes it back to his fiance, and we're left to assume the worst.  I'm also reminded of the original "Invasion of the Body Snatchers," where the hero runs around the entire episode trying to find someone to believe him.

Comment: I loved Twilight Zone - but I do have to wonder, how did that kid (or whoever) get the secret without also going crazy? Email?

Comment: Some kids are just carriers of insanity (as some parents will tell you)